# How DisplayMetrics gets its width and height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the screen width and height for whole platform. So I want to know where should I change ?

As I understand that DisplayMetrics provides the width and height for all apps. How DisplayMetrics gets those width and height ? Any leads is appreciated.

Comment: you want to manually set width and height for any screen and Please , change the question format ?

Answer (score -1):

For getting : width and height :

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: As he clearly mentioned that he knows that DisplayMetrics provides the width and height. he wants to set them via code, and you mentioned how to get them. Got it?
try to read the questions before shooting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

i use this when i made a code to setup wallpaper :

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Comment: the topic and the question are completely different, topic talking about how to get width and height and then ask how to change dimensions !!! please learn how to ask a question, the question is the half of the answer. thanks for understanding

Comment: I think you should read title properly... I didnt ask how to get width and height .. I asked How DisplayMetrics gets its width and height... and I mentioned the details what exactly I want to do with that ...